# When is a probability a function of a probability?

Tags: distributions, expected-value

I am asked to calculate $E(ln (\frac{1}{P(X)}))$ 
Where X is a discrete random variable over
$\chi $ $\in \{1,2,3\}$ with probability mass function 
P(X=1)=0.5,P(X=2)=0.4, P(X=3) = 0.1

I think this would be $\sum_{i=1}^3 P(X=i) ln(\frac{1}{P(X=i)})$

But I am having trouble picturing a real world example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are computing the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), or at least the [nats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)) version of it, which is not a probability. For one thing, Shannon's entropy is not bounded from above to unity.

A function of a probability is a probability if it satisfies [Kolmogorov's probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms). I don't know about a real-world example offhand, but you can find some discussion online about "metaprobability". Closest thing that comes to mind is when a Bayesian defines a [prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) over the possible values of an unknown probability.